# Straight Through Processing in Apache Camel

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, apache-camel

I am interested in figuring out the best way to do straight through processing in Apache Camel.

I have several different components that I am able to start up in the same JVM, which is separate from where my activemq broker. Does it make sense to try to set it up so that my messages get passed from one component to the next, in order, blocking? How would I go about setting camel up to ensure that each message hits every component along the route before the next message is started?

To be more specific: I would like to do this through a configuration of my brokerURI or something. I saw this page:  http://fusesource.com/wiki/display/ProdInfo/Understanding+the+Threads+Allocated+in+ActiveMQ but I am not sure where/how to implement the options - optimizedDispatch seemed to work on the broker destinationPolicy options.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

to start, explicitly configure a single consumer in your routes that consume from queues...

either globally for all connections

```
<bean id="jmsConfig" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="pooledConnectionFactory"/>
    <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="1"/>
    <property name="maxConcurrentConsumers" value="1"/>
</bean>
```

or explicitly per route/consumer

```
 from("activemq:queue:input?concurrentConsumers=1&maxConcurrentConcumers=1")...
```

then, you have a few options.  generally, you'd either use a pipeline pattern to pass messages between steps (synchronously) in a single route.  Or use [camel-direct](http://camel.apache.org/direct.html) to provide synchronous message flow between multiple routes.

```
from("activemq:queue:input?concurrentConsumers=1&maxConcurrentConcumers=1")
    .to(<step1>)
    .to(<step2>)
    ...
```

or if your steps require multiple routes, then connect them using direct...

```
from("activemq:queue:input?concurrentConsumers=1&maxConcurrentConsumers=1")
    .to("direct:step1");

from("direct:step1")
    //perform step1 processing
    .to(direct:step2");

from("direct:step2")
    //perform step2 processing
    .to(direct:step3");
...
```

Comment: So it has to be added on the queue that the consumer is reading from every time? There is no way to configure this for all queues in a brokers control?

Comment: this can be done globally as well...I updated the answer accordingly

Comment: What about setting those async and dispatchAsync options on the broker? is that necessary for straight through processing, and can I use that with TCP transport?

Comment: if your goal is to reduce threads and synchronize everything...then you could set optimizedDispatch=true and dispatchAsync=false, etc.  But, these generally don't need to be tuned unless you have specific threading issues/requirements that need to be addressed.  If you follow my example above, you will guarantee processing order because only a single consumer is allowed.  Also, if you need better throughput but still need ordering of related messages, consider using message groups (http://activemq.apache.org/message-groups.html ), they provide the best of both worlds